# Do there exist infinite sets of non-halting programs such that every program in the set computes every other program in the set?

Tags: turing-machines

> Do there exist infinite sets of non-halting programs such that every program in the set computes every other program in the set, and only programs in that set?

I know there exist programs which compute every other program, by diagonalizing on the library of all possible programs. So there are infinite sets of programs such that every program in that set computes every other program in that set. But what about the second condition, that they compute **only** programs from that set?

This is not a homework question; I am writing a philosophy term paper and would like to cite this fact as evidence for something.

Comment: "I know there exist programs which compute every other program, by diagonalizing on the library of all possible programs." Actually universal Turing machines do not require any "diagonalizing." Not clear what you mean here. This is a topic that requires some precision with language, and using common language helps. What do you mean "computes every other program?" Non-halting programs are always possible to emulate universally, so that's not what you mean.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I'm not very familiar with the topic myself, which is why my language is imprecise. (It's been three years since I took a class on this)

I was imagining a program that proceeds as follows: Go to the first program on the list of all possible programs. Execute the first step of that program. Then go to the second program on the list, and execute the first step of that. Then go back to the first program, and execute the next step. Then go back to the second program... by continuing in this way, diagonally, the program can execute all the steps of all the programs.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "non-halting." At first, I assumed you had the usual meaning, but the standard mean of non-halting program does not compute anything - it just spins. No output.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (and perhaps I don't), then yes it's true.

If every program in a set $\cal P$ of programs "computes every other program in that set", I take this to mean that all the programs in the set compute the same partial mathematical function. Specifically, for a program $P$, let $f_P$ be the function computed by $P$, $D_P$ its domain (the set of integers, say, on which $P$ halts). Then I take your condition to mean: for all $P, Q\in \cal P$, $f_P = f_Q$ (and so of course $D_P=D_Q$).

For *every* program $P$ (or Turing machine $M$, or computable function $\varphi_e$, ... pick your favorite formal system of computation), there are infinitely many other programs $Q$ which compute the same partial mathematical function as $p$ does: $f_P = f_Q$. Some of them actually implement different algorithms, while others arise by "padding" — adding useless instructions. In particular this holds for programs that don't halt on some inputs, those that halt on no inputs, as well as those that halt on all inputs (which compute *total* functions).

As for your mention of diagonalization in the question and in a comment, I don't see how this applies. To judge from your comment, I think you mean *enumeration*. Nor do I see how there are really two parts to the question: unless you means something different than what I imagine, the answer to the first implies the second. In your comment you mention the following "computation":

> Execute the first step of that program. Then go to the second program on the list, and execute the first step of that. Then go back to the first program, and execute the next step. Then go back to the second program... by continuing in this way, diagonally, the program can execute all the steps of all the programs.

This is not a (halting) computation, as you know — computations have finitely many steps.

I see another way to interpret your question. Perhaps you intend a notion like $$\text{line $i$ in program $P$ simulates line $j$ in program $Q$ at step $t$ on input $x$,}$$ 
and you're asking whether there's an infinite set of programs $\cal P$ such that for all $P\in\cal P$, $P$ run on input $x$ has this property — that is, for every $Q\in\cal P$, every line $j$ in $Q$, there is a line $i$ of $P$ which at some step $t$ simulates line $j$ of $Q$ run on $x$. In this case, the "second part" of your question really is distinct: no $P\in\cal P$ should simulate all the lines of any program not in $\cal P$ on any input.

The answer to *that* ought to be No, but the details are relative to the particular formalism involved, which are required to make the definition of "simulates" precise.

Comment: Thanks Brian! The second way to interpret my question sounds more like what I had in mind. 

The programs I am thinking of don't take any inputs, though I suppose it wouldn't change anything to model them as all taking the same trivial input.

Simulation does sound more like the word I was looking for, not computation, since computations are supposed to have finitely many steps.

Why is the answer to that question No? Is there a similar question for which the answer is yes?

Comment: I think it's "No" due to length-of-program considerations. When the formalism is *programs*, your infinite set would in a sense all be interpreters for each other. Any interpreter has a fixed length and can interpret other, arbitrarily long programs, and similarly for universal Turing machines. There's also Rice's theorem, which tells us that you can't computably enumerate all and only all the programs that compute the same function. so it's not clear that any of these programs could generate an list of all & only all others like it -- it seems it can't be so. But again, detail needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think a  more natural (and, more to the point, more likely to be close to the OP's intention) interpretation of the question goes as follows:

> Is there a set $A\subseteq 2^{<\omega}$ such that for every $e\in A$, the collection of functions $f_t(x)=\varphi_e(tx)$, $t\in 2^{<\omega}$, is exactly $\{\varphi_s :s\in A\}$?

I suspect the "non-halting" in the OP was caused by a misunderstanding how universal functions generate all programs (it's not by doing this successively, but by varying the input); of course, I could be wrong.

I've used strings rather than integers as inputs, which seems more convenient here.